# How to show/hide a webform block on nodes of specific content type based on node field value?

Tags: blocks, webforms, 9

I have a webform with machine name "podcast". I am displaying this webform as a block in the nodes of content type with the machine name 'podcast'.
There is a file field with the machine name 'field_podcast_discussion_guide' in the content-type podcast.
I want to show/hide the 'podcast' webform block based on the value present in the field_podcast_discussion_guide field for each node of content type 'podcast'.
If the field_podcast_discussion_guide field has a value, show the 'podcast' webform block, and if this field doesn't contain a value hide the block.
How to do this in Drupal 9?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question doesn't exactly meet our guidelines. You should show that you did some research and include in the question what you have tried so far. Please have a look at the [Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) and make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).